# I have ubuntu 22,cannot connect to internet and when I suspended it this appeared :

Tags: suspend, internet, freeze

```
305.8539061 rfkill: input handler enabled
305.8539121 fbcon: Taking over console
305.9948511 PM: suspend entry (deep)
306.0018191 Filesystems sync: 0.006 seconds
306.5789481 Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
306.5884931 Freezing user space processes
306.5902581 Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
306.590289] DOM killer disabled.
306.5902941 Freezing remaining freezable tasks
306.591124] Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 9.000 seconds)
306.591216] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
```

Comment: What is Ubuntu Pop?

Comment: my bad, a typo, I meant ubuntu 22